# How to call web api with to get byte array .Sample code needed

Tags: java

**Server**

Using below code to return byte array ,but not able to get byte array at client side.

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(getOpenCasesResponse.Content);
var dataStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
httpResponseMessage.Content = new StreamContent(dataStream);
httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
//  httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = bookName;
httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

return httpResponseMessage;
```

***Client***

Below is code I am trying to call from client to get byte array, but not able to get data from server.

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));

var s = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
byte[] mybytearray=  Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
```

Comment: If you want to read the bytes, why are you using `ReadAsStringAsync` instead of `ReadAsByteArrayAsync` or `ReadAsStreamAsync`?

Comment: i tried but that is also not working

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: Its not returning data from server .

Comment: any working sample code will be helpful

Comment: You're going to need to debug your code. For example, what is `getOpenCasesResponse.Content`?

Comment: only header information is coming ,not file data is coming inside content.

Comment: So there's something wrong with your API code. Debug that.